# can't get 'click' event listener to register as user initiated action on Android Chrome in a-frame (to play media)

Tags: aframe

I understand that to start a video in Chrome from within A-frame on Android a user initiated event is needed, but I cannot work out how to get Chrome to accept a click event listener triggered via a fused cursor as a user event.

the following code is in the init of a component attached to a cube.

```
this.el.addEventListener('click',function(evt){
  console.log("clicked");
  var els = document.querySelector('#video');
  els.components.material.material.map.image.play();
});
```

there is a video sphere in the html as follows

```
<a-videosphere id="video" src="#avideo" rotation="0 180 0" ></a-videosphere>
```

and the follow within the assets tags.

```
<video id="avideo" src="video/lowaudio.mp4"></video>
```

When I debug, Chrome returns the following, even though it appears to me that the user is initiating the click even via a cursor fuse.

```
videoClick.js:22 Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only be initiated by a user gesture. @ videoClick.js:22

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture.
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be an actual physical click of the screen, not a synthetic one.

```
document.querySelector('.a-enter-vr-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('video').play();
});
```

Comment: How do you deal with multiple videos that you would like to play at different times in VR, but trigger from within VR without having to touch the screen?

Comment: Not sure mobile browsers even let you play multiple videos. But the Cardboard button will also trigger screen clicks.